# Generate sequence numbers based on column data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have data like below

```
    Transaction_id, Type
    10001            PO
    10002            PO
    10003            PO
    10004            NON-PO
    10005            NON-PO
    10006            PO
    10007            PO
    10008            NON-PO
    10008            PO
```

I have to generate sequence or show the sequence numbers as per below output

```
  Transaction_id, Type,    Sequence
  10001            PO        1
  10002            PO        1
  10003            PO        1
  10004            NON-PO    2
  10005            NON-PO    2
  10006            PO        3
  10007            PO        3
  10008            NON-PO    4
  10009            PO        5
```

```
create table test_data(Transaction_id NUMBER,"Type" Varchar2(100));

insert into test_data(Transaction_id,"Type") values(10001,'PO');
insert into test_data(Transaction_id,"Type") values(10002,'PO');
insert into test_data(Transaction_id,"Type") values(10003,'PO');
insert into test_data(Transaction_id,"Type") values(10004,'NON-PO');
insert into test_data(Transaction_id,"Type") values(10005,'NON-PO');
insert into test_data(Transaction_id,"Type") values(10006,'PO');
insert into test_data(Transaction_id,"Type") values(10007,'PO');
insert into test_data(Transaction_id,"Type") values(10008,'NON-PO');
insert into test_data(Transaction_id,"Type") values(10009,'PO');

commit;
```

data inserted into table

sequence creation:

```
create sequence seq_num start with 1 increment by 1;
```

selection of data:

```
select Transaction_id,"Type",seq_num.nextval    
from test_data;
```

it will give output as per sequence not as per expected output

Please suggest how to achieve requested output

Answer (score 3):

You want to count the number of changes in `type` based on the ordering in `transaction_id`:

```
select td.transaction_id, td."Type", 
       sum(case when prev_type = type then 0 else 1 end) over (order by transaction_id) 
       as "Sequence"
from (select td.*,
             lag("Type") over (order by transaction_id) as prev_type
      from test_data td
     ) td;
```

The subquery determines the previous type using `lag()`.  The outer query simply counts the number of times that it changes.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
 SELECT * , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY type) AS SQUENCE FROM test_data
```

Comment: I think this will not work. Can you please create sample data and share the output?